# broken loop in javascript game

Tags: javascript

I know this one is probably a really simple fix but I don't see it. I'm trying to make an Acey Deucey game in Javascript but for some reason, the game loop seems to be broken. The way the game works basically is like this, the dealer draws two cards and the player makes a bet on whether the next card drawn by the dealer will be in between the first two cards.

Keep in mind, I'm still relatively new to Javascript so that's why I'm struggling with this.

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout});

var deck = [];
var dealerPot = 200;
var playerPot = 50;
var playerBet = 0;

function initializeDeck(d) {    
    for(i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        d[i] = i;
    }
}

function shuffle(d) {
    var l = d.length - 1;
    var toSwap;
    var temp;
    for(i = l; i > 0; i--) {
        toSwap = Math.floor(Math.random()*i);
        temp = d[i];
        d[i] = d[toSwap];
        d[toSwap] = temp;
    }


/* sanity check     
     for(i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        console.log(d[i]);
    }
*/
}

function between(x, min, max) {

    var temp;
    if(min > max) {
        min = temp;
        max = min;
        temp = max;
    }

    return x >= min && x <= max;
}

function setFace(x) {
    var f = x % 13;

    var faces = ["ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "jack", "queen", "king"];

    switch(f) {
        case 1:
            return faces[0];
        case 2:
            return faces[1];
        case 3:
            return faces[2];    
        case 4:
            return faces[3];
        case 5:
            return faces[4];
        case 6:
            return faces[5];
        case 7:
            return faces[6];
        case 8:
            return faces[7];
        case 9:
            return faces[8];
        case 10:
            return faces[9];
        case 11:
            return faces[10];
        case 12:
            return faces[11];
        case 0:
            return faces[12];

    }

}

function setSuit(x) {
    var suits = [" of hearts", " of diamonds",  " of spades", " of clubs"];
    var s = x / 13; 

    if(s <= 1) {
        return suits[0];
    }
    if(s > 1 && s <= 2) {
        return suits[1];
    }
    if(s > 2 && s <= 3) {
        return suits[2];
    }
    if(s > 3 && s <= 4) {
        return suits[3];
    }
}

function deal(x, y) {
    console.log("Dealer draws " + setFace(x) + setSuit(x) + " and " + setFace(y) + setSuit(y));
}

console.log("Welcome! Enter 1 to continue, 0 to quit");
rl.setPrompt('AceyDeucy> ');
rl.prompt();
rl.on('line', function(line) {
    if (line === "0") rl.close();
    initializeDeck(deck);
    shuffle(deck);
    var i = 0;
    var card1;
    var card2;
    var card3;

     while(playerPot != 0 || dealerPot != 0) {

        card1 = deck[i];
        card2 = deck[i + 1];
        card3 = deck[i + 2];

        console.log("Dealer Pot: " + dealerPot);
        console.log("Player Pot: " + playerPot);

        deal(card1,card2);

        rl.question("Place your bet ", function(playerBet){
            rl.prompt();
            console.log(playerBet);

            console.log("Dealer draws" + setFace(card3) + setSuit(card3));
            if(between(card3, card1, card2) == true) {
                console.log("you win!");
                playerPot += playerBet;
                dealerPot -= playerBet;
            }

            else {
                console.log("you lose!");
                playerPot -= playerBet;
                dealerPot += playerBet;
            }       
        });

        i++;
    }

    rl.question("Enter 1 to play again, 0 to quit", function(number) {
        rl.prompt();
    });

}).on('close',function(){
    console.log("Thanks!");
    process.exit(0);
});
```

Comment: This code looks pretty whole to me. No shattered pieces scattered around. So-o-o, there is no problem then?

Comment: Well the deal function runs about 50 times before asking the player for his bet and then once the bet is entered the deal function runs about 50 times and asks the player for his bet again. I'm thinking the condition for the loop is incorrect